# Go to viewController in storyboard from SKView Xcode objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode8, gamekit

I have an app that uses a regular viewController to enter the app.  Then it goes to a viewController that uses a collection view.  When the user taps on one of the collection images they are taken to a SKView via a viewController.  When the user finishes the game they are given the opportunity to go out to the internet to learn more.  Because of age Apple requires a parental gate.  This is implemented through another UIViewController.
My question is how do I get out of the gameScene to the UIViewController.  When I use this code I get the following error.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Gate"];
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

       [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

No visible@interface for 'GameScene6' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:conpletion:'

Someone suggested that I use the uiViewController associated with the GameScene which is GameViewController6  but I'm not sure how to do this can someone show me some code to go from a GameScene to a viewController in storyboard?

Would I use something like this

```
 - (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(goToGameOverViewController:)
     name:@"GoToGameOverViewController"
     object:nil];
}

-(void)goToGameOverViewController:(NSNotification *) notification {

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Gate"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

this works and takes me to the correct view controller which is a parental gate.
When the parental gate is successful the user is taken to a webpage.  The problem now is when the user taps on the "back to APP" button in the upper left corner the view controller presented is a blank black page.  When tapped on the app crashes.

Any idea on how to return to the Gameview I just left?

Comment: Set a breakpoint before calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. What's the *self's* type?

Comment: self is GameScene6.m this is declared in error No visible@interface in my original post. Can't set breakpoint because error keeps anything from running.

Comment: So what's the line causing crash?

Comment: [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL]'

Comment: it is an error that won't let the app even build

Comment: You need to pass a ViewController object to your SkView. Then, call this method on that object, not self.

Comment: I don't know how to do this.  Can you point me to a tutorial on this or post some code that would teach me.  Thx